# Using http.dart to Call CoinMarketCap API. Not sure what to do

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, coinmarketcap

So I'm new to flutter and dart and am trying to call from the CoinMarketCap API. I'm using the HTTP package to call the data and the API. I'm not super familiar with them but here's what I came up with...

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<Payload> getCryptoPrices() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD"),

        headers: {
          'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'my-key',
          "Accept": "application/json",
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Payload payload = payloadFromJson(data.body);
      return payload;      
    }
  }
```

I get a couple of errors:

`The name 'Payload' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument`

`The function 'payloadFromJson' isn't defined`

`Undefined name 'data'`

Am I not successfully importing JSON? I'm not sure how to fix the error. What do I need to do to successfully make a API Call? Any feedback would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CODE UPDATED #1**

```
import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';


class CoinMarketCap {
  static const _apiKey = '111111111111111111111111111111';
  static const _url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency';

  static Future<void> getListingLatest(int limit) async {
    var url = '$_url/listings/latest?start=1&limit=$limit&convert=USD';
    var result = await HttpReqService.get<JMap>(
      url, 
      auth: AuthType.apiKey,
      authData: MapEntry('X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY', _apiKey)
    );
    var coins = (result?['data'] as List).cast<JMap>().map<String>((e) => e['name']);
    print(coins);
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await CoinMarketCap.getListingLatest(7);
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Output:

```
(Bitcoin, Ethereum, Tether, USD Coin, BNB, XRP, Cardano)

Job done!
```

Comment: What do I have to paste into the `pubspec.yaml` dependencies to run `'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart'`?

Comment: Follow the instructions for [that package](https://pub.dev/packages/wnetworking/install) only. It's simple.

Comment: I have installed `wnetworking` and it works. However it only lists bitcoin and I want it to list all of the coins. I have changed `/listings/latest?start=1&limit=1&convert=USD'` to `/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5&convert=USD'` to show the top 5 as a test but it still only prints the first one. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I've updated my code to list first 7 coins and it is working, I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Is there perhaps json format settings I need to change within visual studio code?

Comment: IDE is irrelevant. Have you run my updated code?

Comment: Yes it outputs the 7 coin names but I need it output each individual data for each of the 7 coins not just the names. I tried changing `var coins = result?['data'];` and kept varying it to print all of the data but it still will only print bitcoins. What do I do to print the data for all of the coins?

Comment: Bro, at this point I can say you are lacking in basic knowledge about Dart. You need to delete `.map<String>((e) => e['name'])` only. I'm done with this question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. 'Payload' is not a flutter class so it does not exist. were you trying to use a Custom made Class?
2. the 'payloadFromJson' error means it does not exist so you probably did not import it properly if it is in another class
3. Undefined name 'data' means that data has not been defined if you want the body of the response use 'response.body'